# How to Create Multiple Rows in Mysql Against One ID (Not Necessarily Primary Key)?

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a reservation system for my school project. It is based on PHP and MYSQL.

The system allows a user to register. After successful login, the users can make a reservation which is stored in the following table in phpmyadmin. 
[User Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWvoq.png)

When a user registers, he gets a user_id. When a user makes a reservation, the data is inserted into the table against the same user_id. But when the user tries to make another reservation, there is no way to store the information of the next reservation.

**The question is how do I allow the user to make several reservations?** 
The user_id is my primary key so I understand it is not possible to create multiple records against one primary key.

Do I have to create a new reservation table and link it to user_id through a Foreign key relationship>? But if my reservation table has a primary key, then several records cannot be inserted against one primary key.

Somehow, each reservation must be linked the unique user_id so that the user can check all the bookings under his name.

Each reservation also needs a unique ID which can be used to cancel/update the reservation.

I believe it must be a basic MySQL question. Something like creating a new reservation table and connecting it with user_ID but I am unable to think of a concrete solution.

Your help is very much appreciated. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Make table `users`

then at least 2 fields `id, name`

then make table reservations and its One-To-Many relation so you need to put foreign key in reservation(many side)

`reservation`

`id, name, user_id`

then to get reservations from user 1 use select with join

```
 SELECT * FROM reservations r JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.id WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this question. How do I create a one-to-many relationship for the reservation table?

Comment: just by puting user_id into reservation table, additionally it's good to add foreign key constraint but it isn't necessary

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification Robert, I will implement that and will let you know the outcome.